# Move All Files to Another Folder Except a Specific One in Bash

Tags: bash, mv

I am using this command line to move files except "files2feed.php" from a folder to another one.
It works in terminal but not in my bash script.

```
mv /media/site/public_html/ftp/category1/!(files2feed.php) /media/mysite/public_html/ftp/in/
```

I also tried:

```
mv /media/site/public_html/ftp/category1/\!(files2feed.php) /media/mysite/public_html/ftp/in/
```

What should I change for a bash script usage?

Comment: Did you set the `extglob` option (`shopt -s extglob`) in your script?

Comment: Hi Renaud, I didn't. I wasn't aware of this option. It works properly now. Thank you!

Comment: See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).